# Fetch request to Potter api - returing list of characters - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, jsx

I'm trying to make a Fetch request in my React component to a Harry Potter api, https://www.potterapi.com/, in order to retrieve a list of characters, and then map out their attributes on the page.

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Do I need to specify "mode: no-cors" inside of the fetch request? Also, I have been given an api key by the app, but I'm not sure if I'm using this in the correct way? (See code below).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Robert

```
      componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters", {
          "headers": {        
            "x-rapidapi-key": "******************"
          }
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(posts => {
            this.setState({ posts: posts });
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error));
      }
    
    
      /* 
        1. Add the method componentDidMount()
        2. Call fetch("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters")
        3. Then call .json() on the response
        4. Take that and set it as the value of posts in state
        5  Add a catch to log out any errors
      */
      render() {
        console.log(this.state.posts);
        return (
          <header>
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            <ul>
              {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                <li key={post.key}>{post.house}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </header>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Get help from `postman` for find is correctly api?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF Or maybe using `curl -i https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters -H'x-rapidapi-key:xxxx'` @Robert Young Can you check that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*` ?

Comment: According to the documentation, you can provide a query parameter `key` which contains your API key, so more like `/v1/characters?key=xxx`